# How to properly suppress a section of a Classic ASP page

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a rather complex (>3k lines) Classic ASP Page that is supposed to suppress certain section based on the value of the CountryID.  I've created boolean variables and set them to true if the CountryID of the Job is a particular value.  The initial logic is as follows:

```
  blnUSJob = False
  blnCanadaJob = False
  blnAUJob = False
  blnNZJob = False
  nCountryID = 0

  If GetJobCountry(nJobAd_ID) = "CA" Then
     blnCanadaJob = True
     nCountryID = 2
 End If
```

I've created markup that renders if the blnCanadaJob evaluates to True:

```
<% 
if not blnCanadaJob then 
%>      
<tr>
<td width='30%' class='StandardLight' style="background-color:#dddddd" 
    valign='middle' align='right'>
<b>For replacement positions enter the following information for previous 
    incumbent</b>
<b>Name:</b><span class="Required">nbsp;*</span>&nbsp;<input type="text" 
    name="txtName" class="StdFieldName" value ="<%=strName %>" size="50" maxlength = 
    "50" /><br>
</td>
</tr>
```

Now, I need to ensure that this markup is suppressed for other CountryIDs.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?  Should I repeat the above markup with the evaluation statement for the specific country ID?  Or, is there a more elegant way of handling this?

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more options, a select statement would be best ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_conditionals.asp) f.i.):

```
Select Case GetJobCountry(nJobAd_ID)
  Case "CA", "US":
    nCountryID = 2
    blnCanadaJob = True

  Case Else:
    blnCanadaJob = False

End Select
```

You can set option variables like `blnCanadaJob` there easily and it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a little:

```
if GetJobCountry(nJobAd_ID) = "US" then

%>
<tr>
<td width='30%' class='StandardLight' style="background-color:#dddddd" 
    valign='middle' align='right'>
<b>For replacement positions enter the following information for previous 
    incumbent</b>
<b>Name:</b><span class="Required">nbsp;*</span>&nbsp;<input type="text" 
    name="txtName" class="StdFieldName" value ="<%=strName %>" size="50" maxlength = 
    "50" /><br>
</td>
</tr>
%>
end if
```

Comment: So, if I need to suppress the section for jobs in US and Canada would it be If GetJobCountry(nJobAd_ID) <> "US or GetJobCountry(nJobAd_ID) <>"CA then

Comment: Sure, but you may want to assign that DB value to a variable to shorten your code.